# Shouldn't the following program crash?

Tags: c, linked-list

I was going through a program that is supposed to "flatten" a link list.
To see what I mean by flatten, here's the code from the link
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flattening-a-linked-list/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// A Linked List Node
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *down;
} Node;

/* A utility function to insert a new node at the begining
   of linked list */
void push (Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* allocate node */
    Node* new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->right = NULL;

    /* put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->down = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Function to print nodes in the flattened linked list */
void printList(Node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->down;
    }
}

// A utility function to merge two sorted linked lists
Node* merge( Node* a, Node* b )
{
    // If first list is empty, the second list is result
    if (a == NULL)
        return b;

    // If second list is empty, the second list is result
    if (b == NULL)
        return a;

    // Compare the data members of head nodes of both lists
    // and put the smaller one in result
    Node* result;
    if( a->data < b->data )
    {
        result = a;
        result->down = merge( a->down, b );
    }
    else
    {
        result = b;
        result->down = merge( a, b->down );
    }

    return result;
}

// The main function that flattens a given linked list
Node* flatten (Node* root)
{
    // Base cases
    if ( root == NULL || root->right == NULL )
        return root;

    // Merge this list with the list on right side
    return merge( root, flatten(root->right) );
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    Node* root = NULL;

    /* Let us create the following linked list
       5 -> 10 -> 19 -> 28
       |    |     |     |
       V    V     V     V
       7    20    22    35
       |          |     |
       V          V     V
       8          50    40
       |                |
       V                V
       30               45
    */
    push( &root, 30 );
    push( &root, 8 );
    push( &root, 7 );
    push( &root, 5 );

    push( &( root->right ), 20 );
    push( &( root->right ), 10 );

    push( &( root->right->right ), 50 );
    push( &( root->right->right ), 22 );
    push( &( root->right->right ), 19 );

    push( &( root->right->right->right ), 45 );
    push( &( root->right->right->right ), 40 );
    push( &( root->right->right->right ), 35 );
    push( &( root->right->right->right ), 20 );

    // Let us flatten the list
    root = flatten(root);

    // Let us print the flatened linked list
    printList(root);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is that while merging the lists, the NULL pointer is never appended after the end of the result link list, so when we call `printList()`, shouldn't the program crash because the link  list doesn't have a NULL in the end?

Comment: No, the NULL pointer is stolen from the head_ref via `new_node->down = *head_ref;` assignment. (only on the first call, when *head_ref is still NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This code looks relatively fine.

Let's look at it this way. We know that every `Node` object is valid. The last one in each of the two lists, has `last->down == NULL`. When we do the `merge()`, we never change the value of the new `last->down`, so it retains the correct value of NULL.

To try to be a bit clearer, we only change the value of `node->down` when we have two nodes, and we only change one of them each time. So the last iteration of `merge()`, we will be passed a pointer to a node, and a pointer to NULL. In that case, we will leave the final node alone (and it is required to have been pointing to NULL, or to a chain of elements that eventually points to NULL).

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` function detects NULL pointers up front:

```
if (a == NULL)
    return b;
if (b == NULL)
    return a;
```

These return values are assigned when `merge()` is called recursively:

```
result->down = merge( a->down, b );
…
result->down = merge( a, b->down );
```

The `flatten()` function worries about using the `right` pointers. However, AFAICS, nothing resets the right pointers.  The `printList()` function doesn't look at them, but if you did print using the right pointers too, then you'd find some eccentricities in the behaviour.  Try this modified `printList()`:

```
void printList(Node *node)
{
    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", node->data);
        if (node->right != NULL)
        {
            putchar('[');
            printList(node->right);
            putchar(']');
        }
        node = node->down;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The output is:

```
 5[ 10[ 19[ 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 19[ 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 7 8 10[ 19[ 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 19[ 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
] 20 20 22 30 35 40 45 50
```

So, the code isn't perfect, but no — I wouldn't expect it to crash.